# Open document without any prompts

Tags: document

We have a page that aggregates data from a number of SP sites, the user can then click a button to open a bunch of documents relevant to them.

At the moment I am using window.open() to open the documents. This usually prompts the user with the dialog asking them if they want to open or save the document. Is there a way I can open the document without any dialog? I've tried the editDocumentWithProgID2 method but that still p[prompted me

Answer (score 1):

I think you're probably out of luck as it's a massive security risk. Imagine a malicious document sitting on a server that is forcibly opened. Much badness.

If you're in an Intranet environment you might be able to accomplish it, but this would require a combination of:

- configuring the browser to trust your site
- installing an addin to browser
  that would allow the forcible opening
  of documents